# Can you use Krippendorff's Alpha to assess reliability of an entire measure using one case study?

Tags: spss, reliability, agreement-statistics

I am interested in using Krippendorff's Alpha for a dataset containing a large number of raters to assess the reliability of using an assessment tool for case studies, which contains 8 items with ordinal (yes / no) responses (e.g., does this individual meet x criteria?).

Typically I have seen kalpha being used to assess the inter-rater reliability of independent items within tools using two or more case studies. For example, the inter-rater reliability of 40 raters of item x would be examined by calculating expected / observed reliability across 2 / 3 / 4 case studies. In the case of the current tool, this would produce 8 kalpha values for items 1 through 8.

However, I would instead be interested in calculating a single kalpha value across all eight items for the entire measure, using only one case study that has been rated by 40 raters.